# how to set ports for GCP load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

Three of  Node.js web server are all listing on port 3000, how can I set port configuration(backend and frontend) for load balancer?

I set backend port 3000, frontend 80, but it's not working. I tried to use iptable to redirect 80 to 3000 in the instance, it didn't work. How can I set the load balancer ports?

Comment: The load port settings are correct: Frontend 80, Backend 3000. 1) Did you create a firewall rule allowing traffic on port 3000? 2) Did you create a health check? If yes, is the health check failing? 3) You do not need the iptables entry. I would delete that entry.

Comment: 4) Verify that your backend is working. Assign an external public IP address to the Compute Engine instance. Verify that your web server is working: `curl http://IP_ADDRESS:3000` or use a web browser.

Comment: Do not use iptables for anything, everything you need to configure is provided by GCP

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you set url_map to direct traffic to different backend services?
2. You mentioned that there were three web servers, were they served as an identical service? If not, you need to define them separately. One backend service for one web server. For example, set webserver A as backend service A, and webserver B as backend service B ... etc.
3. You could define port for `each` backend service, which is about which port you would like the traffic to be directed from instance group to each instance.
4. Simply speaking, if three web servers are all different, you need to...

   - Define three ports for three web servers on the instance group
   - Set corresponding firewall-rules to open required ports on each instance
   - Run your web server on each instance on specified ports
   - map the traffic to correct backend server with url-map
   - default front end with 80 port should work okay, if needed, you could build a 443 front end to provide HTTPS with automatically renewed SSL by Google
   - Above mentioned steps you could easily find on Google Cloud Console.

If you would like to know how each component on GCP LB in detail, you could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@raycodingjourney/lets-understand-gcp-load-balancer-and-build-one-step-by-step-148ce319c8b8)
    - you could only read the concept of how instance and instance group and backend service connect from each other.